# Fetch API throws an error while fetching from steam web api

Tags: javascript, fetch

I want to fetch a information from steam web api's 'GetFriendsList' endpoint.When I am using fetch to do this from my front end javascript file.Im getting an error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v1/?key=<apikey>&steamid=76561198364464404' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I went to mdn and saw I must use

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
```

in the fetch option.I did add these and no difference same error,I also added

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

It worked this time but no response was returned from the steam web api.
I am really new to this.This is the first time using fetch.Any help regarding this is appriciated.THANK YOU.

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/1743358239838884448/

Comment: In a nutshell, that says that you cannot make steam api requests from a browser, but you can from a server. So you have to proxy your requests through a server.

Comment: How can i do a proxy request?.Or i must define a route and hit the route through ajax or axios and get information from there

Comment: It means you have to write your own server -- for example using node.js and express, or python+flask/django, php+laravel, something like that, whatever server-side tool you prefer -- and then in your browser-based javascript, you make an http request to your server, and your server makes an http request to api.steampowered.com